# Tricking a windows 10 computer into thinking a USB being plugged in is a mouse for code execution

Tags: windows, hardware, windows-10, usb

Is it possible to "trick" a Windows 10 PC into thinking a flash drive is a mouse to execute code on the machine? If so, how?

Note: I'm not trying to do anything malicious. All of this is strictly for learning purposes.

Comment: Have you heard of "Bad USB"?

Comment: No, I haven't @forest

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/badusb

Comment: None of those questions/answers teach how to make a bad usb though.

Comment: If you want to actually _make_ one, you can look into the Teensy USB development board, which is an active USB device. If you want to compromise the firmware of a normal USB _flash drive_, you're out of luck. That's something you'd have to do yourself and would differ for each flash drive (you'd need to reverse engineer the firmware and find an exploit assuming you don't use an SPI programmer or something to rewrite the chip itself, since there really aren't public "how to" guides for that due to its complexity).

Comment: If you want to do this to learn, I'd recommend learning how to use a Teensy USB for this purpose. It'll teach you a lot about how different USB class drivers are selected and how HIDs work.

Comment: [trick a Windows 10 PC into thinking a flash drive is a mouse](https://www.google.com/search?q=trick+a+Windows+10+PC+into+thinking+a+flash+drive+is+a+mouse)

Comment: The most famous device is a "Rubber Ducky" from Hak5. There are tons of tutorials on making your own.

Comment: It should be noted that none of the ways of simulating a mouse will lead to "code execution" on the machine. There are some ways with simulating a keyboard and using shortcuts to open the command line, then "typing" pre-defined commands into it.

Comment: no, a flash drive is just a flash drive. you can make something that acts like both, but it won't start life as a legit flash drive.

Comment: @dandavis In many cases, you could modify an existing, legit flash drive to do this due to the way they update firmware (even if they're not meant to update firmware). Of course, if you physically modify it, you can do it with nearly _any_ flash drive. After all, a flash drive is a microcontroller connected to a flash chip.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the USB protocol, every device has a data structure that it provides on connection that describes the device.  This structure could also list multiple devices (as if the device was a hub with devices attached).

To make a flash drive pretend to be a mouse, you would have to reprogram the firmware in the device to present a different device descriptor, and may require extensive knowledge of the internals of the flash disk and a way to change the firmware.  However there are many [tools and tutorials](https://hackmag.com/security/rubber-ducky/) available.

It might be much easier to use a device with a known programming capability, such as one of the Arduino variants. Several Arduino devices actually have examples of how to make them act like a USB keyboard or mouse.  With a small Arduino such as the Teensy, it might even be possible to disguise it as a flash drive.

One possible legitimate use of this:  I programmed an arduino to read infrared signals from TV remotes and translate those to keystrokes on a simulated keyboard.